# TFS 2010 Jenkins Integration

Tags: .net, tfs, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm new to both TFS & Jenkins, As a part of DevOPs, We would like to do Continues Integrations With TFS 2010 and latest Jenkins.

1. Automatically build our web project on every checkin. - (Build should trigger from TFS or Jenkins)
2. Automatically deploy green builds to development and/or test environments. - (across domains)
3. Can we do similar automated deployment for Databases (mainly MSSQL 2008)

Comment: Why not use Team Build and Release Management? You're already using TFS, you might as well use the entire stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Jenkins and TFS just like you can integrate Jenkins with many other VCS.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin

You should however consider the features that you loose by using Jenkins. You don't get a maintained relationship between builds and work items. You don't get to use Gated Checkin. You cant relate Test Results with builds and thus can't get a holistic view of your coverage. You don't get Test Impact Analysis which will tell you which tests, manual and automated, that you need to run when code changes.

To be brutally honest there is no value in using Jenkins with TFS and in fact the loss of functionality is crippling to any ALM strategy.